# How to append a file with for loop based data in php

Tags: php, arrays, file

I want to append a txt file with for loop data using php. Here is my code

```
$post_array = array('hdnItemTypeID', 'hdnItemType', 'hdnItemCode',  'hdnCost', 'txtDescription');
        foreach ($post_array as $pos) {
            foreach ($_POST[$pos] as $id => $row) {
                $_POST[$pos][$id] = $row;
            }
        }
$ids = $_POST['hdnItemTypeID'];
        $ItemTypeID = $_POST['hdnItemTypeID'];
        $ItemType = $_POST['hdnItemType'];
        $ItemCode = $_POST['hdnItemCode'];
        //$Discount = $_POST['txtDiscount'];
        $Discount = '0';
        $UnitCost = $_POST['hdnCost'];
        //$Amount = $UnitPrice + $Discount;
        $Description = $_POST['txtDescription'];
        $size = count($ids);
 for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
            // Check for part id
            if (empty($ids[$i])) {
                continue;
            }
            $items = array(
                ':ItemTypeID' => $ItemTypeID[$i],
                ':ItemType' => $ItemType[$i],
                ':ItemCode' => $ItemCode[$i],
                ':Description' => $Description[$i],
                ':UnitCost' => $UnitCost[$i],
                ':Amount' => $UnitCost[$i] +$Discount,
                ':Discount' => $Discount
            );
            file_put_contents('Check.txt', print_r($items,true));
        }
```

But only single array is getting is getting in the file. How to get althe array values in it?

Comment: see http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cant use

```
file_put_contents('Check.txt', print_r($items,true), FILE_APPEND);
```

See http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 2):

`file_put_contents` by default overwrites everything. Use:

`file_put_contents('Check.txt', $items, FILE_APPEND);`

[REFERENCE](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-put-contents.php)